# Determine the magnitude of the resultant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

The two structural members, one of which is in tension and the other in compression, exert the indicated forces on joint O. Determine the magnitude R of the resultant R of the two forces and the angle θ which R makes with the positive x axis (measured counterclockwise from the x axis).

I have the resultant force but I don't know how to get theta.

[image: problem1]

Comment: Do you have the $x$ and $y$ components of the resultant?  If so, then just use $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$

Comment: My x component is 3.81616. My Y component is -1.07517. When I use arctan(y/x) i get -15.7347. That answer is apparently incorrect.

Comment: It could be that they want a positive angle.  I'm not sure how many tries you have, but what about $360-15.7347=344.2653$?  At any rate, you should definitely get an angle in the lower-right quadrant, so you can't be too far off the right track...

Comment: You were correct. Thanks for your help.